# Ionic 2 Build succeeds but no APK generated

Tags: build, apk, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2. I can use ionic serve fine. When I try to use the build command, or the run command for either Android or iOS, the command succeeds, but no apk nor ipa is generated. There are no build folders under the platorm folders.

E.g.

```
ionic build android
```

outputs the following:

```
> ionic-app-scripts build

[00:35:55]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45 
[00:35:55]  build prod started ... 
[00:35:55]  clean started ... 
[00:35:55]  clean finished in 5 ms 
[00:35:55]  copy started ... 
[00:35:55]  ngc started ...  
[00:35:55]  copy finished in 93 ms 
[00:36:07]  ngc finished in 12.19 s 
[00:36:07]  webpack started ... 
[00:36:14]  webpack finished in 7.00 s 
[00:36:14]  uglifyjs started ... 
[00:36:14]  sass started ... 
[00:36:15]  sass finished in 922 ms 
[00:36:15]  cleancss started ... 
[00:36:16]  cleancss finished in 924 ms 
[00:36:22]  uglifyjs finished in 8.68 s 
[00:36:22]  build prod finished in 27.88 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I assume you already have the android sdk installed.

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

It will generate the apk, but it will take a good time.

Comment: I've used Ionic v1 plenty of times in the past, so I'm familiar with the CLI and aware of the commands to run. The issue is they don't work now that I'm trying them with v2. Android platform has already been added, as has iOS. I have also tried removing and then re-adding the platforms and then building. No difference.

Comment: You have installed cordova and configured the android sdk?. I just tried it on my computer and generated it without problems

Comment: Yes, cordova is installed. Android SDK is also installed. Path variables are all configured as well.